# How to show different size images on a site with lots of images

Tags: image, file-upload, scalability

For an image intensive size like 500px, flickr, instagram etc which serve lots of images with different sizes and users constantly upload images whats the best way to store and display different size images.
Same image is usually displayed in different sizes, like thumbnail, modal window size and big size etc (like on ecommerce sites).
Also for dynamic size grids like http://500px.com/flow where images are all dynamic sizes spanning multiple rows and columns.

Do these sites create all these different sizes and store different version of site or its done on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, these sites create a few versions of the image when they are uploaded. Common examples are small (thumbnail), medium, large, full-size. These transformations are done at upload-time, as there is a large performance penalty of resizing so many images on the fly.

Comment: so if they have a new feature and want to show a different size image they will be going through all existing pictures and creating a new size?

Comment: Well, if you have the full size image, and you want to make a new sized image (between medium and large let's say), it's trivially easy to go through all the full sized images and make new ones. In general, when you make a web app (or any other complex system), you make what you need right now, and not what you might hypothetically need in the future. [This link explains it more clearly.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)